# Spaces - how do I stay on the Space I am using when opening other apps on other spaces

Tags: osx-spaces

I like to open a number of different apps in different windows, ans as soon as there is any activity in any space the screen jumps to that space. how can I open an app in a space and not jump to it form the space I am working in. this function is available in various versions of Linux but not in a mac.

Comment: [Hyperspaces](http://thecocoabots.com/hyperspaces/) is a commercial "addon" for Spaces. Don't know if it has that feature, though.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for this my self, and found the answer here:
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2008021122525348

To Summarize:
Use the following Terminal command

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool NO
```

and restart the dock.

```
killall Dock
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please refrain from just posting a link, but rather give a quick summary of what it says.